# Tailwind css border position

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a border position 
nomal css :

```
border-top: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid black;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
```

how can i implement with tailwind css?

Answer (score 1):

Implement with *tailwind css* like this `class` below:

```
<div class="border-[10px] border-solid border-transparent border-b-black"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class as follows

```
<div class="border-[10px] border-solid border-transparent border-b-black"></div>
```

Here,

- `border-[10px]` means `border: 10px;`
- `border-solid` means `border: solid;`
- `border-transparent` means `border: transparent ;`
- `border-b-black` means `border-bottom:  black ;`